# Graphviz: the vertical edge is impact by [style=invis], how to make the edges vertical

Tags: graphviz

I have some digraph, which I have to use the `[style=invis]` to define the node order; but I found the original vertical edge is impacted by `[style=invis]`, below is the digraph:

```
digraph G { 
    edge [dir=none]; 
    R_35->p92;
    R_35->p93;
 
    c_p92 [shape=diamond]; 
    {rank=same; p92 -> c_p92};
 
    R_38 [shape=box];
    c_p92->R_38;
    R_38->p21;
 
    c_p93 [shape=diamond]; 
    {rank=same; p93 -> c_p93};
 
    R_36_0 [shape=box];
    R_36_0->p96;
    R_36_1 [shape=box];
    R_36_1->p97;
    R_36_0->R_36_1
    c_p93->R_36_1;
 
 
    c_p92->p93[style=invis];
    R_38->R_36_0[style=invis];
    p21->p96->p97[style=invis];
 
 
 
    {rank=same;  p92; c_p92; p93;c_p93;};
    {rank=same; R_38; R_36_0; R_36_1};
    {rank=same;  p21; p96; p97;};
}
```

I hope the edges from node "c_p92" to "R_38", from node "R_36_1" to "p97" are vertical, but they are impacted by the `[style=invis]` that, it seems they are attracted by each other and the edge is tilt. Can any one help me to figure out how to make these edges vertical?

Comment: Please add an image of what you see to the question. Also specify the version `dot` that you are using. When I look at http://www.webgraphviz.com/ it all looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the same `group` to all nodes of a 'string' of nodes should be aligned vertically - for example `group=a` for nodes`c_p29, R38, p21` and `group=b` for nodes `c_p93, R_36_1, p97`:

```
digraph G { 
    edge [dir=none];
    R_35->p92;
    R_35->p93;
 
    c_p92 [shape=diamond, group=a]; 
    {rank=same; p92 -> c_p92};
 
    R_38 [shape=box, group=a];
    c_p92->R_38;
    p21[group=a];
    R_38->p21;
 
    c_p93 [shape=diamond, group=b]; 
    {rank=same; p93 -> c_p93};
 
    R_36_0 [shape=box];
    R_36_0->p96;
    R_36_1 [shape=box, group=b];
    p97[group=b];
    R_36_1->p97;
    R_36_0->R_36_1
    c_p93->R_36_1;
 
 
    c_p92->p93[style=dotted];
    R_38->R_36_0[style=dotted];
    p21->p96->p97[style=dotted];
 
 
 
    {rank=same;  p92; c_p92; p93;c_p93;};
    {rank=same; R_38; R_36_0; R_36_1};
    {rank=same;  p21; p96; p97;};
}
```

Graphivz tries to align nodes of the same group.

[image: graphviz result]

(changed invis edges to dotted to see what's what)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to get vertical edges (assuming rankdir=TB) is to use the **group** attribute (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/group/ and https://forum.graphviz.org/t/a-question-about-the-group-attribute-what-does-straight-mean/548/2).  Like so:

```
digraph G { 
    edge [dir=none]; 
    R_35->p92;
    R_35->p93;
 
    c_p92 [shape=diamond  group=V1]; 
    {rank=same; p92 -> c_p92};
 
    R_38 [shape=box group=V1];
    c_p92->R_38 [color=red];
    R_38->p21;
 
    c_p93 [shape=diamond]; 
    {rank=same; p93 -> c_p93};
 
    R_36_0 [shape=box];
    R_36_0->p96;
    R_36_1 [shape=box group=YY];
    R_36_1->p97 [color=red];
    R_36_0->R_36_1
    c_p93->R_36_1;
 
    c_p92->p93[style=invis];
    R_38->R_36_0[style=invis];
    p21->p96->p97[style=invis];
 
    {rank=same;  p92; c_p92; p93;c_p93};
    {rank=same; R_38; R_36_0; R_36_1};
    {rank=same; p21; p96; p97 [group=YY]}
}
```

Giving:
[image]